# Display selected image in the MediaPlaceholder component

Tags: block-editor

I'm trying to make a simple block with an image from media library. It looks like this in the editor:

[image]

After select the image from library, the image are not displayed in the editor. the interface remains unchanged, as if no image had been selected. How do I make the image I have selected appear in the editor?

### block.json

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
    "apiVersion": 2,
    "name": "giraldez-blocks/image-with-text",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "title": "Imagen con texto",
    "category": "giraldez",
    "icon": "format-image",
    "description": "Imagen y texto con el diseño inclinado de giraldez",
    "supports": {
        "html": false
    },
    "textdomain": "giraldez-blocks",
    "editorScript": "file:./index.js",
    "editorStyle": "file:./index.css",
    "style": "file:./style-index.css",
    "attributes": {
        "imageUrl": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "imageId": {
            "type": "number"
        },
        "imageAlt": {
            "type": "string",
            "source": "attribute",
            "selector": "img",
            "attribute": "alt",
            "default": ""
        }
    }
}
```

### edit function

```
import { MediaPlaceholder } from "@wordpress/block-editor";
import { BlockIcon } from "@wordpress/block-editor";

export default function Edit({ attributes, setAttributes }) {
    return (
            <div {...useBlockProps()}>
                <MediaPlaceholder
                    onSelect = {
                        ( el ) => {
                            setAttributes( { 
                                imageUrl: el.url,
                                imageId: el.id,
                                imageAlt: el.alt 
                            } );
                        }
                    }
                    accept="image/*"
                    icon={<BlockIcon icon="format-image" />}
                    allowedTypes = { [ 'image' ] }
                    multiple = { false }
                    labels = { { title: 'The Image' } }
                >
                </MediaPlaceholder>
            </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I would study how the core image block uses the component. That block conditionally [renders an `img`](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/ec8b279887010c6437fe4130abb623732ce19f3e/packages/block-library/src/image/edit.js#L317-L332) when the url has been set. It might also be important to provide the [`value` prop](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-editor/src/components/media-placeholder/README.md#value) to `MediaPlaceholder` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the interface remains unchanged, as if no image had been selected. How
> do I make the image I have selected appear in the editor?

It remains unchanged because we actually need to manually add a preview of the image, just like the core Image block does, and you can check the [source on GitHub](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-library/src/image/edit.js), but basically, you could just add a simple `<img>` tag above, below or even inside the `MediaPlaceholder` element/area.

And here's an example for the 3rd option, where we need to pass a React **component** to `MediaPlaceholder` via the [`mediaPreview` property](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/04639ad1d33ab2d8fbcf2a74885c913887d661b7/packages/block-editor/src/components/media-placeholder/README.md#mediapreview):

```js
const mediaPreview = !! attributes.imageUrl && (
    <img src={ attributes.imageUrl } />
);

return (
    <div { ...useBlockProps() }>
        <MediaPlaceholder
            ... your other props
            mediaPreview={ mediaPreview }
        />
    </div>
);
```

Or for images uploaded to the media library, if you want, you can instead display a thumbnail of the image like so, which uses `useSelect` and `getMedia` to fetch the image details (from the REST API), and then I'm displaying the medium-sized thumbnail image:

Preview (WordPress v6.0.1):

[image: Preview image]

1. Load `useSelect`, e.g. add at the top in your file:

   ```js
   import { useSelect } from '@wordpress/data';
   ```
2. Replace the `const mediaPreview = ...` part with:

   ```js
   const { imageUrl, imageId, imageAlt } = attributes;

   const thumbnailUrl = useSelect( select => {
     const image = imageId && select( 'core' ).getMedia( imageId );
     return image && image?.media_details?.sizes?.medium?.source_url || imageUrl;
   }, [ imageId ] );

   const mediaPreview = !! thumbnailUrl && (
       <p>
           Image URL: { imageUrl }<br />
           Thumbnail URL: { thumbnailUrl }<br />

           <a href={ imageUrl } title={ imageAlt }>
               <img src={ thumbnailUrl } />
           </a>
       </p>
   );
   ```

   **Note:** The above `[ imageId ]` means if the attachment/image ID is changed (e.g. a new image was selected from the media library), then the `thumbnailUrl`'s value will also change. Also, if a medium-sized thumbnail isn't available, then I'm displaying the full-sized image, i.e. `imageUrl`.

#### Additional Notes

1. I'd pass a `value` to `MediaPlaceholder` so that the selected image will be pre-selected in the media modal. E.g.

   ```js
   <MediaPlaceholder
       ... your other props
       value={ { // pass an object!
           id: attributes.imageId,
       } }
   />
   ```
2. You can use a single `import` declaration to [import multiple "module exports"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#import_multiple_exports_from_module) from a module. For example, this imports 3 exports (a hook and 2 components) from the @wordpress/block-editor package:

   ```js
   import {
       useBlockProps,
       MediaPlaceholder,
       BlockIcon,
   } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
   ```
3. For elements with no content (or no inner text), you can just use the self-closing format like `<MediaPlaceholder ... />` and no need for `<MediaPlaceholder ...></MediaPlaceholder>`.

   You know, just like the `img` tag where we *don't* use `<img ...></img>` .. :) And thus if you noticed it, my examples actually used that self-closing format.

Comment: You're my hero! Thank you very much for the explanation so detailed and perfectly adapted to my level.